# Set Color for Pie Chart using HighChart + JSON data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am generating a pie chart from data stored in JSON format. I am trying to change color according to the JSON value.

Ex : if value @ json[0]['data'][0][0] = "FAILED"   //setColor(RED).

I was able to set the color for column stack charts using options.series.color, however when I tried to use this option with pie chart its converting data into series and unable to render the chart on a container.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  function getData(id) {
    $.getJSON("pie.php", {
      id: id
    }, function(json) {
      option.series = json;
      chart = new Highcharts.chart(options);
    });
  }
</script>
```

can we set the color in getData function only before calling 'chart' or do i need to use Highcharts.setOptions() and define the color codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better option is to create series based on your json data. This is how you can do to specify color based on data.

```
var serie = {
    data: []
};
var series = [serie];

jQuery.each(jsonData, function(index, pointData) {

    var point = {
        name: pointName,
        y: pointData.Value,
        color: pointData.Value == 'FAILED' ? 'ff0000' : '00ff00',    
        serverData: pointData
    };

    serie.data.push(point);
});
chart.series = series;
```

OR

Have a look at this easier version

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prgme3a5/)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

var data = [{
    "name": "Tokyo",
    "data": 3.0
}, {
    "name": "NewYork",
    "data": 2.0
}, {
    "name": "Berlin",
    "data": 3.5
}, {
    "name": "London",
    "data": 1.5
}];

    
// Highcharts requires the y option to be set
$.each(data, function (i, point) {
    point.y = point.data;
    point.color = parseFloat(point.data) > 3 ? '#ff0000' : '#00ff00';
});


var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },

    series: [{
        data: data
    }]

});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

we can set highchart custom color by setOption function which is as

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors: ['#F64A16', '#0ECDFD',]
});
```

It sets color to my pie chart.

Another solution for dynamic 3D color

Actually this customization for theme selection Here it is

3 colors sets to color variable

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
        $.each(colors, function(i, color) {
            colors[i] = {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#0ECDFD'],
                    [0.3, '#F64A16'],
                    [1, color]
                ]
            };

        });
```

& assign directly in series

```
 {
  type : 'column',
    name : 'bug',
    data : [],
    color : colors,                 
    pointWidth : 28,
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply however this is not the solution i am looking for .. i am getting values from JSON file and need to define color according to those values.

Comment: you can set your color option in json data also.